# Is there any difference between two constructors of the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy?

Tags: sqlbulkcopy, sqlclient

The `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` type has four constructor:

```
public SqlBulkCopy(SqlConnection connection);
public SqlBulkCopy(string connectionString);
public SqlBulkCopy(string connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions copyOptions);
public SqlBulkCopy(SqlConnection connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions copyOptions, SqlTransaction externalTransaction);
```

Is there any differences between calling `public SqlBulkCopy("someConnectionString")` and `public SqlBulkCopy("someConnectionString", SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no difference.

There is no value set for the field `_copyOptions`: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs#L183

Which mean the default value is 0 (equivalent to `SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default`): https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopyOptions.cs#L14

The constructor `public SqlBulkCopy(string connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions copyOptions);` call the `public SqlBulkCopy(string connectionString);` constructor and set the `_copyOptions` field: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs#L309

So you will get exactly the same behavior